# How can I delete all versions of an object in a versioning-enabled minio bucket using java SDK?

Tags: minio, minio-client, minio-java-sdk, versioned-object, minio-versioning

I could not find any parameter for deleting all versions of an object using Minio java SDK. For example, the following code only marks an object as deleted, but it does not really delete the object from the bucket:

```
minioClients.removeObject(RemoveObjectArgs.builder().bucket("bademjoon").object("tokhm").build());
```

In other words, I need to know the equivalent java method/property of the below Yes/No button to delete all versions of an object in mino.

[image: Deleting all versions of a Minio object]